# WCF or ASMX WebService

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have been asked to create a web service that communicates with Auth.NET CIM and Shipsurance API.  My web service will be used by multiple applications (one a desktop and another a web application).

I am confused whether I should build a WCF or an asmx web service.

Auth.NET CIM and Shipsurance API have asmx web services which I would be calling in my newly created web service. So is WCF the right approach or can I stay with asmx?

Comment: recommended reading: [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) -- _"if you... don’t want your question to get instantly closed... — try to keep Gorilla vs. Shark in mind."_

Comment: @gnat i did not ask which one is superior or anything else .My question was would wcf work in this case .Since i have not used it someone familiar with wcf may be able to help me out

Comment: There is also Web API which is MS newest entry to the web services stable. Also have a look at Service Stack as an alternative. Have a look on Stackoverflow, there are lots of posts on these techs and the pros and cons of each

Comment: There is no reason to use WCF over a simple .asmx if the .asmx can do the job. Only step up to WCF if you need features beyond that, e.g. TCP or named pipe access as well as SOAP over HTTP.

Comment: @Carson63000 but isn't asmx an old way to do web service ? wont there be any performance upgrade if i go for WCF

Comment: @karthi - yes, .asmx is the old way. In my professional experience, WCF adds considerable complexity in return for functionality which you may or may not need, so if you don't need it, don't use it. If there's any performance difference, I would imagine that would favour an .asmx also.

Comment: @Carson63000 Great. I understand.Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for WCF. If you read the differences between wcf and webservices you may understand the necessity of wcf over webservices.

WCF offers duplex communication with bindings and improved security. you can configure your data transfer mode and security. I suggest you to read WCF Bidnings.

First of all, wcf is webservice. you can either create a WCF Project library(creates a *.dll) or WCF service application (Appication that you can host).

You can communicate with WCF to a old webservices. WCF has better features and security which you may want to consider before going to web services

Comment: Thanks for replying and not voing down.Some one in the chat room just told me that web api would work .What do you think?The main confusion i have is i will be calling other auth .net webservices from the web services that i create will that cause any perfomance issue

Comment: No it wont, the reason behind choosing WCF will be security and flexibility. Choosing web.api which is rather a new technology and easy to implement. If you're new to programming i would suggest WCF(which is easy to learn and gives you a outline of webservices.) If you're good at c#, there you go with Web Api. Web Api is modernized and will be suppored for a long time over wcf. Web APi requires a bit more knowledge in the code practices and standards. So that you wont mess it up. Its up to you to go for API or WCF. both are good. Toss a coin.

Comment: am not new to programming been working on .net for a couple of years. WCF seems to be a safe bet.Thanks a lot :)